# Anaconda won't start after PC reboot

Tags: powershell, reboot, anaconda

I was happily coding this morning using Spyder/Anaconda, then my computer needed a reboot, Spyder/Anaconda wont start at all.

If I try and use the Anaconda Prompt it shows the below error:

```
failed to create process.
Invoke-Expression : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is
an empty string.
At C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:70 char:36
+         Invoke-Expression -Command $activateCommand;
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterB
   indingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAl
   lowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

[image: Error Message]

Comment: The reason for the reboot... it was Windows updates? I ask because that's a Powershell error (.psm files are powershell scripts). It's possible that an update changed how the Invoke-Expression commandlet works and the psm script trips over the change. You might want to check the issue tracker for anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen after an update to Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime on my system.  Reinstalling Anaconda fixed the problem.